# How to increase performance in AWS Lambda service?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created simple Lambda function in java and exposing it using API gateway. The Billed duration for lambda function in **60 ms**, api gateway taking **40 ms** more to response so the latency is **100 ms** here.

***Note : Memory Size: 1.5GB    Max Memory Used: 40 MB. All the response time which mentioned here is when lambda function in warm state (active)***

If we test the latency in *AWS API Gateway* its taking **100 ms**.

If we test it in *Rest client* in my local machine, the latency is **1500 ms**.

If we consume (call) this lambda function in *EC2 instance for same region and same account*, the latency is **200 ms**

Why this much variation in Rest client, we get to know that the reason is network latency. How can I increase its performance because we need to consume this Lambda function in native app its taking almost 1500 ms.

For the web app which deployed in *EC2 Instance for same region and same account we are getting fair response* that is* **200 ms**.

Comment: You have to consider that Lambdas are not the best option for real-time systems. If the client calls a function that has not be called for some time, the delay will be greater that one that is constantly used. Services that are used in an irregular pace and have no problem to wait one or two seconds matches best with this service.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** your best option for now is to deploy lambda in a region as close to your client as possible

**Long answer:** this is a problem of any web based application, not just lambda/api gateway. There are a few techniques to combat this.

- cache content. API Gateway automatically comes with a CloudFront distribution so if you cache responses they are served from the nearest POP to the client.
- multi region deployments. If you have clients in many disperse geographical locations you can deploy lamda + api gateway in several of those regions then use route53 with latency based routing to serve the client from the nearest location.
- Lambda @edge. This is currently only in preview and only supports node.js for now, but would be ideal for responding to requests from the nearest POP

Comment: Note that the API Gateway caching feature does not use the CloudFront distribution to cache at the POPs, but rather caches the data within API Gateway at the region where the API is deployed.  Also note, that it is not currently possible to set-up a multi-region deployment with automatic request routing with API Gateway.

Comment: In my testing the difference between nearest and farthest regions was never significant--that's not where the latency lies in API Gateway. So unless that improves, it's probably best used in scenarios where latency is not an issue (not forward-facing web apps).